# Why does the border not line up with content?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I'm new to CSS/HTML, and I can't figure out why the border does not line up with the content/image. The bottom border is offset by a few pixels, leaving a gap between the edge of the picture and the actual border. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```css
/* Body */

body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/bf/58/a4bf58276d674626f52092e2194f79d8.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Title */

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0% 1% 2% 1%;
  padding: 0% 10% 0% 10%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 225%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Left Body Items */

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}


/* Presentation Text */

#intro_text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
  padding: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 130%;
}


/* Skyline Photo */

#photo {
  border-width: 3%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Bar Menu */


/* Right Body Items */

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}


/* Booking Button */

#button {
  /* Booking Button */
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2%;
  border-color: white rgb(253, 0, 232) rgb(253, 0, 232) white;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Informations */

#infos {
  /* General Information */
  background-color: rgba(253, 0, 232, 0.6);
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.bold_underlined {
  /* Information Headings */
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#metro {
  /* Metro Information */
  color: gold
}
```

```html
<h1>Rooftop Bar, in the center of NYC</h1>
<!--Title-->
<div id="blocks">
  <!--Body-->
  <div id="left">
    <!--Left Body Items-->
    <div id="intro_text">
      <!--Presentation Text-->
      The 23rd Street Rooftop Bar welcomes you every day for a unique New York experience. In the iconic neighborhood of Chelsea, the bar presents a magnificent view on the New York skyline at night. With DJs from all around the world, the Rooftop Bar offers
      a vast assortment of music to suit all tastes: from Disco to Hip-Hop, passing by Pop and Electro. The perfect party for you!
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="photo">
      <!--Skyline Photo-->
      <img src="https://www.thepresslounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Press_Lounge_0028-HDR-2-Edit-1600x900.jpg" alt="View from the rooftop." width="100%">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="menu">
      <!--Bar Menu-->
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <!--Right Body Items-->
    <div id="button">
      <!--Booking Button-->
      <p>
        Book now!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="infos">
      <!--Informations-->
      <p>
        <!--Age & ID-->
        <em>All guests must be aged 21 or older.<br>
                        A valid ID is required.<br></em>
        <br>
        <!--Opening Hours-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Opening Hours:</span><br> Mon: 5pm-1am<br> Tue: 5pm-1am<br> Wed: 5pm-1am<br> Thu: 5pm-1am<br> Fri: 5pm-2am<br> Sat: 2pm-3am <br> Sun: 2pm-8pm<br>
        <br>
        <!--Contact Info-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Contact Info:</span><br>
        <em> +1 917-722-2439</em><br> 
        <em>&nbsp info@rtnyc.com </em><br>
        <br>
        <!--Location-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Access:</span><br>
        <span id="metro"><strong>Ⓜ</strong> 23rd Street</span><br>
        <em>119 W 23rd St, New York, NY 10011, USA</em>
      </p>
      <!--Embeded Map-->
      <iframe src="https://snazzymaps.com/embed/187161" width="100%" height="250px" style="border:none;" title="Google Map of Rooftop Party location"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wp9cn3kt/1/

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the image dimensions have nothing to do with it. Using a background image instead of an image tag is a really abd approach. The white space is called: `inline decender space`. Simply fix is to use `display: block;` on the image so it doesnt get a decender space from an inline-element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: @tacoshy Ah I see, makes sense. You are correct. Although I would like some context on 'really bad approach'

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava using `display: block;` is litterally a one line solution. And simplicity should always win. Using a background image instead requires mutliple lines. Also it cant be ensured that the full image is shown in the correct aspect ratio is shown. The containign element has to be sized correctly for that. Screen readers dont recognize a background-image... Overall a few possible issues that can emerge aswell as you need to change way to much codelines compared to `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `display: block;` property to your image and that's it.

```css
/* Body */

body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/bf/58/a4bf58276d674626f52092e2194f79d8.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Title */

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0% 1% 2% 1%;
  padding: 0% 10% 0% 10%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 225%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Left Body Items */

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}


/* Presentation Text */

#intro_text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
  padding: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 130%;
}


/* Skyline Photo */

#photo {
  border-width: 3%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Bar Menu */


/* Right Body Items */

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}


/* Booking Button */

#button {
  /* Booking Button */
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2%;
  border-color: white rgb(253, 0, 232) rgb(253, 0, 232) white;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(253, 0, 232);
}


/* Informations */

#infos {
  /* General Information */
  background-color: rgba(253, 0, 232, 0.6);
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.bold_underlined {
  /* Information Headings */
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#metro {
  /* Metro Information */
  color: gold
}
```

```html
<h1>Rooftop Bar, in the center of NYC</h1>
<!--Title-->
<div id="blocks">
  <!--Body-->
  <div id="left">
    <!--Left Body Items-->
    <div id="intro_text">
      <!--Presentation Text-->
      The 23rd Street Rooftop Bar welcomes you every day for a unique New York experience. In the iconic neighborhood of Chelsea, the bar presents a magnificent view on the New York skyline at night. With DJs from all around the world, the Rooftop Bar offers
      a vast assortment of music to suit all tastes: from Disco to Hip-Hop, passing by Pop and Electro. The perfect party for you!
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="photo">
      <!--Skyline Photo-->
      <img src="https://www.thepresslounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Press_Lounge_0028-HDR-2-Edit-1600x900.jpg" style="display: block;" alt="View from the rooftop." width="100%">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="menu">
      <!--Bar Menu-->
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <!--Right Body Items-->
    <div id="button">
      <!--Booking Button-->
      <p>
        Book now!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="infos">
      <!--Informations-->
      <p>
        <!--Age & ID-->
        <em>All guests must be aged 21 or older.<br>
                        A valid ID is required.<br></em>
        <br>
        <!--Opening Hours-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Opening Hours:</span><br> Mon: 5pm-1am<br> Tue: 5pm-1am<br> Wed: 5pm-1am<br> Thu: 5pm-1am<br> Fri: 5pm-2am<br> Sat: 2pm-3am <br> Sun: 2pm-8pm<br>
        <br>
        <!--Contact Info-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Contact Info:</span><br>
        <em> +1 917-722-2439</em><br> 
        <em>&nbsp info@rtnyc.com </em><br>
        <br>
        <!--Location-->
        <span class="bold_underlined">Access:</span><br>
        <span id="metro"><strong>Ⓜ</strong> 23rd Street</span><br>
        <em>119 W 23rd St, New York, NY 10011, USA</em>
      </p>
      <!--Embeded Map-->
      <iframe src="https://snazzymaps.com/embed/187161" width="100%" height="250px" style="border:none;" title="Google Map of Rooftop Party location"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple fix, you can try put the `id="photo"` in the img element instead of the container (if no need to have a container).

```
<div> <!--Skyline Photo-->
    <img id="photo" src="https://www.thepresslounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Press_Lounge_0028-HDR-2-Edit-1600x900.jpg" alt="View from the rooftop."  width="100%">
</div>
```

Styling in original code:

```
#photo {
  border-width: 3%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(253, 0, 232);
}
```

Comment: what is that suppose to do? Adding an ID to an element will not change its layout (at least not without CSS).

Comment: With the existing css in the code, putting the id to the img element will wrap the border around the image without white space. Of course, if the intent is to keep the id at the container, then changing the <img> display to block will remove the white space. Always nice to see different methods for different purposes.